# how to catch request in express + nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

could you please tell me    how to catch request in express + nodejs ? I want to catch all request like `/in/docs` ,`/es/docs`,`/fr/docs`..

```
const server = express()

server.get('/in/docs', (req, res) => {
    console.log('====kk==')
    app.render(req, res, '/')
})
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
})
```

currently, I am doing hard cording like this it only works with `/in` .I want to catch all request `/fr`,`/en`.

```
server.get('/in/docs', (req, res) => {
    console.log('====kk==')
    app.render(req, res, '/')
})
```

Comment: Something like `'/*/docs'` will matching /anything/docs, or, if you need to grab the value of "anything" you can use route parameters: `'/:lang/docs'`, then you can access the value of lang using `req.params.lang` in your callback

Comment: thanks for answering .This '/*/docs'` will also called when user request `/en/docs/something`

Comment: so is it work if I make two handlers one is this `'/:lang/docs'` and other is `'/:lang/docs/:something'`

Comment: You can make a route path that contains a regex that would cover all the desired languages.

Comment: can you share your answer

Answer (score 0):

Use **route parameters** using colons:

```js
server.get('/:language/docs', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.language); // gives 'in' if you specify 'in', 'fr' if you specify 'fr', etc
});
```

You can nest parameters as much as you like, and that will give you an object in the `req.params` field.